# How to adjust the width of a horizontal rule element

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with setting the width of `<hr>` elements. I mean I want my `<hr>` to be displayed half of the full width like this image:

[image]

As you can see the `<hr>` element is between the `<h1>` tag and paragraph and it's half of screen full width.

I have searched and all I got was to setting the `<hr>` element like this:

```
<hr size="30">
```

But that just does not work. So do you know how to set the width of `<hr>` element?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the style attributes of the hr element in css

```
hr {
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hr.half-width{
  width:50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then add `class="half-width"` to the hr element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following things

- Move `<hr />` inside title element [`<h2>` in this example]
- Add `padding-left:25%` and `padding-right:25%` to title element
- Add `text-align:center` to title element

```css
h2{
  font-size:50px;
  padding:0 25%;
  text-align:center;
}


h2 hr{ width:100%;height:10px;background:#000;}
```

```html
<h2>
This is a very big title
<hr />
</h2>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also

```
hr {
    margin: 0rem 10rem 0rem 10rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adjusting font size of your hr tag

```
hr{
font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not the hr tag. probably it's the border bottom for the span container the text. so the width of the span will define the line width. use padding for the span to adjust the line-width.

I did a search and it seems this is the theme you are using: https://theme.co/x/

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, there is an attribute for this, the only thing you need to do is use the following attribute. In this case, I am going to it a width of 75%. I hope that it'll be helpful to you

```
<hr width="75%">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use attributes to do that.

`<hr width=50%">` or `<hr style="width:50%;">`

Also, you can use,
`height:5px;` to change thickness of the rule.
`background: red;` to change the color of the rule.

Thank you.