# How do you change length of an hr tag?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

How do you change length of an hr tag?

```
<hr>
```

Takes the full length of the browser. I tried setting padding and margin but no effect.  Any solution for this using plain css or using Bootstrap 5?

Comment: A few side notes: "Takes the full length of the browser" - The correct term is actually document. And in the title, the correct term is not "length". It's "width".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust the width of a hr tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502050/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-a-hr-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set margin for the hr tag. The following would work

```css
hr {
  margin: auto 220px
}


/* just for demo*/
.div {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='div'> div - 1</div>

<hr>

<div class='div'> div - 2</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write the following style tag on your html.

```html
<style> hr{margin: auto 220px;}</style>
<hr>
```

[Get more information here.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)