# How to adjust the width of a horizontal rule element, to an input element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to automatically adjust the length of the hr element to the length of the input element using CSS.

Also an animation that is executed when the focus is on the input.

I saw this solution on stackoverflow for the h2 element: [How to do it with h2 element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502050/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-a-horizontal-rule-element)

Code:

```css
h2{
  font-size:50px;
  padding:0 25%;
  text-align:center;
}


h2 hr{ width:100%;height:10px;background:#000;}
```

```html
<h2>
This is a very big title
<hr />
</h2>
```

I have tried it with the input element, but it does not work.

My Code:

```css
hr.underline {width: 0%;}


input.input:focus hr.underline{
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    background-color:#17e13f;
    border:none;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <label for="1">Eingabe</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" id="1">
            <hr class="underline">
        </input>
    </div>
```

But this wont work.
Does anyone know how, or is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are closing your input tag which is wrong `input` tag is self closing...
`what if did:`using `max-content` on the parent `div`then giving `width:100%` to `.underline` on `focus` which means 100% of the parent. and `transition: width 0.25s ease-in-out;` for smooth animation.

```css
    div{
        display:flex;
        gap:5px;
       }
    span {  
        display:inline-block;
        width: max-content;
        
    }
    
    .input:focus~.underline {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .underline {
        height: 2px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #17e13f;
        width: 0%;
        transition: width 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<div>
        <label for="1">Eingabe</label>
        <span>
        <input class="input" type="text" id="1">
        <hr class="underline">
        </span>
        
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without div? I don't want to underline the label but have it at the same height.

Comment: yes you can i have updated the answer